# How to apply authentication with passport-google-oauth in a mern app with json web token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, mern, passport-google-oauth

Recently i am working for a organization. they told me use oauth with jwt, no local authentication. i used passport-google-oauth20 and jsonwebtoken package. I am having problem in frontend react part. how to to get the data from backend with fetch or axios?

here is my code
**server.js**

```
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"],
  })
);
app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { session: false }),
  generateAccessToken,
  function (req, res) {
    if (req.token) {
      const email = req.user.email;
      const token = req.token;
      return res.status(200).json({ email, token });
    } else res.status(400).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
);
```

**token.js**

```
exports.generateAccessToken = (userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "1h",
    issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER,
  });
  return token;
};
```

**Uselogin hook**

```
export const useLogin = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null);
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext;

  const login = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    const response = await fetch("localhost:4000/auth/google/callback", {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      },
    });
    const json = await response.json;

    if (!response.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(json.error);
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(json));

      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: json });
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  return { login, isLoading, error };
};
```

how can i get the user mail and token from the backend?
I know i can access the page through `window.open("localhost:4000/auth/google,"_self")`, but then how can i retrive the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the via the headers or the url params :

```
router.get("/google/callback",passport.authenticate("google", {
   session: false,
   failureRedirect: "api/auth/login/failed",
}),async (req, res) => {
 console.log({ userInCallback: req.user });
 res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/mail=req.user.email`);
}
```